# How do I access and update ng-model in controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ngmodel

So I have this angular directive defined:

```
angular.module('photoSynthesysApp')
.directive('tagList', function(){
  return {
    template: '<div class="tag-form"> <label> LABELS </label>'+

'<button class="btn-xsmall" ng-click="clicked = !clicked">+</button>' +
'<div ng-show="clicked">'+
  '<input type="text" ng-model="newTag">     '+
  '<button ng-click="vm.addTag()"> Add </button>' +
  '</div>'+
'<ul>'+
  '<div ng-repeat="tag in vm.tagListFromDatabase">' +
  '<li>{{tag}}</li>' + '</div>'+
'</ul>'+
'</div>',

controller: taggerController,
controllerAs: "vm",
restrict: "E"
  }
});

function taggerController() {
  this.tagListFromDatabase = ["Bridges","Arches","Roads","Towers"];
  this.clicked="false";
  this.addTag = function(){
    this.tagListFromDatabase.push(this.newTag);
    console.log(this.newTag);
  };
}
```

Console.log gives me undefined, doesn't print anything. I don't understand why it shouldn't.

Also, I'm using template like this because I couldn't figure out how to do templateUrl, but I can figure that out later I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `newTag` property bound to controller (`vm`), however in template you bind `ngModel` to the scope object, not controller.

Correct code would be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.newTag">
```

Note, `vm.newTag` binds model to controller, while `newTag` alone binds to the scope.

Comment: Thank you so much :) That was very helpful.